# How to manage undo for OSX Services?

Tags: cocoa, service, osx-lion

Services are triggered in the context of an application. For example one service may richly format the text in paste board and paste it on the application that requested it.

Is it possible for the service to get reference to its parent's `NSUndoManager` and modify its undo history?

Answer (score 0):

Services are triggered in the context of an application, *conceptually*, but they are not actually executed in that application's process.

Undo-ability is the responsibility of the target application. If a service is pasting something into an app, it's going to end up sending a `-paste:` message up the responder chain of the target app's front-most window. If an "endogenous" paste operation in the target app is undoable, I would expect the "exogenous" paste operation to also be undoable. Similarly, if the app doesn't support undo for paste operations then I wouldn't expect a service-sourced paste to be undoable.

Services are isolated from the target application by the pasteboard, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000850-97688). They will not be able to get the NSUndoManager from the application (or any other object) -- think of what a huge, gaping security hole that would be!  It is probably possible to send an AppleEvent to an application from a system service, but that's about it.